# How to download files form remote directory using python?

Tags: python, django

I have a remote **directory** with mp4 files and I need to download them into my Desktop . 
So basically I need to download a  **remote directory** with given url . How to do it ?

**I dont want to download  single file**

Comment: You mean how to do it python django?

Comment: good ftp usage in Python here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11573992/2886270

Comment: I want to download one folder from sftp server , I can only find examples of single file download here