# What's the easiest way to retrieve FTP files based on a list of filenames (in multiple FTP directories) - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ftp, ftplib

In FTP, the structure looks like this:

```
main_folder / year / month / day / multiple csv files
```

For example:

```
main_folder / 2020 / 02 / 03 / '2020-02-03_01.csv', '2020-02-03_02.csv', '2020-02-03_03.csv', .....

main_folder / 2020 / 03 / 03 / '2020-03-03_01.csv', '2020-03-03_02.csv', '2020-03-03_03.csv', .....
main_folder / 2021 / 01 / 01 / '2021-01-01_01.csv', '2021-01-01_02.csv', '2021-01-01_03.csv', .....
```

So each year has 12 folders (one for each month), each month contains multiple folders (one for one day), and each day have multiple `csv` files (filename is consisted of the `date_xx.csv`).

I have a list of filenames that I want to download, for example:

```
example_list = ['2021-08-09_01.csv', '2021-08-09_02.csv', '2021-08-10_12.csv',
                '2021-08-10_03.csv']
```

My current code behaves like this: extract the date `year/month/day` from the filename -> then construct the corresponding dir in FTP, for example, for file `'2021-08-09_01.csv'`, it will look at all the files under dir `main_folder/2021/08/09`, but if I use the complete directory to tell FTP to only look at the specific file, it gave me error `ftplib.error_perm: 550 No such directory.`

This is the code:

```
file_dir = "main_folder/2021/08/09/2021-08-09_01.csv"

ftp_conn = open_ftp_connection(ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password, file_dir)
ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS(host)
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.cwd(file_dir)
```

I'm a bit confused here, how can I tell FTP to look for those files in the corresponding directory and read the data of them (end goal is to publish to s3 bucket)

Comment: When changing directory, you have to do it to the dir itself, not the file in the dir. Try `ftp.cwd(main_folder/2021/08/09)` then afterwards, download the file.

Comment: After this, how can I tell FTP to only download the target file instead of downloading all the files under `main_folder/2021/08/09`?

Comment: Give me a few minutes I will make an example for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot (I've been struggling with FTP for a couple of days...)

Comment: Just give the actual file name to the `retrbinary` call. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11573817/850848#39719174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
import ftplib, os

example_list = ['2021-08-09_01.csv', '2021-08-09_02.csv', '2021-08-10_12.csv', '2021-08-10_03.csv']

FTP_IP = "1.2.3.4"
FTP_LOGIN = "username"
FTP_PASSWD = "password"
CURRENT_DIR = os.getcwd()
MAIN_DIR = "/main_folder"

with ftplib.FTP(FTP_IP, FTP_LOGIN, FTP_PASSWD) as ftp:
    for entry in example_list:
        filesplit = entry.split("-")
        directory = "main_folder/"+filesplit[0]+"/"+filesplit[1]+"/"+filesplit[2].split("_")[0]
        ftp.cwd(directory)
        with open(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, entry), 'wb') as f:
            ftp.retrbinary(entry, f.write)
        ftp.cwd(MAIN_DIR)
```

The file will be downloaded to the directory, where you execute the python script from with the same filename as those on the server.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, what if I don't have a list of filename, I just want to download every csv file available in FTP, instead of changing FTP dir lots lots of times, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Isn't that exactly the opposite of what you have asked for before?: *"how can I tell FTP to only download the target file instead of downloading all the files under"*

Comment: Yeah it's true, I realized that I need both mechanisms for my user case, I finally worked them out, thanks for the help!